# Docker swarm and cloudflare dns

Tags: docker, ip, docker-swarm, cloudflare

I have a docker-swarm set up in digital ocean.
For now there's only 1 master node but more will be added soon.

I use cloudflare dns for this one, and provided the master node's IP as A record IP.
It does work, I am not really sure that this is the correct way though.

Furthermore, I am wondering which IP should I provide to cloudflare when having multiple master nodes?

Any advice on this will be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any IP you want and Swarm will do routing and load balancing for you. Because of `mesh routing` you automatically publish your service to all nodes which is part of the swarm network .

As your services will evolve you may need to have more custom rules for the routing. In such case you can introduce a new layer of load balancing done by `nginx`, `haproxy`, `traefik` or any similar tool.

The most simple setup after default swarm routing is to use [nginx as load balancer](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/load_balancing.html).

Comment: Thanks @achempion, I have already setup an nginx load balancer inside the swarm. Question is more about which IP I can provide to cloudflare dns and ensure fault tolerance.
If I use the IP of master #1 for example, it will work fine if node is up. But if master #1 fails then it's gonna be down. I am looking for a solution that will not need to update the dns each time a new master node is added.

Comment: You can use load balancer from cloud companies, it's pretty standard offering and point your dns to that IP address but if balancer from cloud company is down your cluster if unreachable. You can use load balancer from cloudflare as well.

Comment: Yes but by using cloudflare load balancer, each time the swarm scales I will need to update the balancer with the additional node's ips. And that's what I'd like to avoid.

Comment: Most likely if you are using balancer from the same cloud as servers, you can configure it to automatically add nodes which have special tag.